# Script to calculate and extract results using bash loops and AWK in a hierarchical directory structure

Tags: bash, shell, awk, directory, openfoam

I have the following [directory](/questions/tagged/directory) structure with certain files of interest, on which I have to do calculation/ arithmetic operations using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk).

```
$ mkdir DP1/postProcessing/0/ DP2/postProcessing/0/ DP3/postProcessing/0/;
$ touch DP1/postProcessing/0/wallShearStress.dat DP1/postProcessing/0/wallShearStress_0.02.dat DP2/postProcessing/0/wallShearStress_0.dat DP2/postProcessing/0/wallShearStress_0.1.dat DP3/postProcessing/0/wallShearStress_0.05.dat DP3/postProcessing/0/wallShearStress_0.000012.dat
masterDir/;

$ tree masterDir/
masterDir/
├── DP1
│   └── postProcessing
│       └── 0
│           ├── wallShearStress_0.02.dat
│           └── wallShearStress.dat
├── DP2
│   └── postProcessing
│       └── 0
│           ├── wallShearStress_0.1.dat
│           └── wallShearStress_0.dat
└── DP3
    └── postProcessing
        └── 0
            ├── wallShearStress_0.000012.dat
            ├── wallShearStress_0.05.dat
            └── wallShearStress.dat
```

**Expected output**

```
DP     File_processed               Ouput_value #Optional header
DP1    wallShearStress_0.02.dat          <some result using AWK>  
DP2    wallShearStress_0.1.dat        <some result using AWK>  
DP3    wallShearStress_0.05.dat     <some result using AWK>
```

My (very basic) attempt failed where the script only returns files three times for the last directory found:

```
$ for i in $(find -type d -name "DP*"); do
>     for j in $(find . -type f -name "wallShearStress*" | tail -n 1); do
>         echo $j;
>         awk 'NR == 3 {print $0}' $j; # this just for example ...
>         # but I wanna do something more here, but no issue with that
>         # once I can get the proper files into AWK.
>     done;
> done;
./DP3/postProcessing/0/wallShearStress_0.05.dat
./DP3/postProcessing/0/wallShearStress_0.05.dat
./DP3/postProcessing/0/wallShearStress_0.05.dat
```

**Problem definition:** I want to,

- First, find in each directory, the file named `wallShearStress*.dat`. where,
- the file of interest should be with the highest number at the ending. (To clarify, there are multiple `wallShearStress*.dat` files present in a directory, e.g. for `DP3` only `DP3\postProcessing\0\wallShearStress_0.05.dat` should be chosen for processing as it has higher precedence than `DP3\postProcessing\0\wallShearStress.dat`, similarly only `DP1\postProcessing\0\wallShearStress_0.02.dat` and `DP2\postProcessing\0\wallShearStress_0.1.dat` should be chosen)
- Do arithmetic operations with awk on the chosen `wallShearStress*.dat`, for each directory and output in the `masterDir` as a `.txt`/`.csv` file as follow:

**Questions**

- What's wrong with the approach?
- Any better approach? (keep in mind that issue is with getting the proper files, not AWK).

I prefer [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) + [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) (since it's easier for me to understand than if someone comes up with other programming languages). Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Thanks for pointing the mistake out. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a for loop for the parent directories and use find for the subdirectories. If your `sort` has the `-V` flag use that.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for d in masterDir/DP*/; do
  find "$d" -type f -name 'wallShearStress*'| sort -Vk2 -t.| head -n1
done
```

To loop through the output you can use a while read loop.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r files; do
  echo Do something with "$files"
done < <(for d in masterDir/DP*/; do find "$d" -type f -name 'wallShearStress*'| sort -Vk2 -t.| head -n1; done )
```

---

Another option as per OP's request

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for d in masterDir/DP*/; do
  while IFS= read -r files; do
    echo Do something with "$files"
  done < <(find "$d" -type f -name 'wallShearStress*'| sort -Vk2 -t.| head -n1)
done
```

- `-t, --field-separator=SEP  use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition` sorting using the `.` as field separator.
- The `<()` Is [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html), it is some sort of a file, a named pipe to be exact see the output of `ls -l <(:)`, and in order to read from a file you need the `<` redirection sign and it needs to be separated from `<( )` otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Can you please add some explanation such as: 1. why `done <<(for d in DP*/;` fails, 2. role of `2`, `.` in `sort -Vk2 -t.`? Another note, isn't it possible to make the syntax look like a while loop inside the for loop?

Comment: You can pipe the output to a `while read loop` yes but it will be in another subshell and that's just how I would write it.

Comment: @massisenergy, I have updated the answer with your while loop inside the for loop.

Comment: I edited a few parts of the code to match the expected output.